# Modify names of variables

Tags: r, ggplot2, correlation, r-corrplot

I am trying to modify the variable labels, that is, my variable "h_ex" represents "household expenses", and I would like "household expenses" to appear when doing my corrplor, in addition to how these changes would be applied to the rest of the package ggplot?

```
corrplot(data, method = 'color', type = 'lower',tl.col = 'black',addCoef.col ='white', number.cex = 0.7, diag=FALSE, cl.pos = 'r')+ theme(axis.text = full_name_vars)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can rename the variables in the dataset.  The labels are simply the variable names.  Here's an example with `mtcars` first, without changing names and then changing a couple of the variable names next.

```r
library(corrplot)
library(dplyr)

corrplot(cor(mtcars), 
         method = 'color', 
         type = 'lower',
         tl.col = 'black',
         addCoef.col ='white', 
         number.cex = 0.7, 
         diag=FALSE, 
         cl.pos = 'r')
```

[image]

```r
new_mtcars <- mtcars %>% 
  rename("Miles per Gallon" = mpg, 
         "# Cylinders" = cyl) %>% 
  select(where(is.numeric))
corrplot(cor(new_mtcars), 
         method = 'color', 
         type = 'lower',
         tl.col = 'black',
         addCoef.col ='white', 
         number.cex = 0.7, 
         diag=FALSE, 
         cl.pos = 'r')
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-10-26 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>